# Return failure code from pre-commit GIT Hook if test fails

Tags: git, bash, gulp, git-bash

I have a gulp task `test` which uses mocha to run my unit tests.

I want to run the unit tests as part of a GIT `pre-commit` hook.

So basically my `pre-commit` file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gulp test
```

The problem I have is that even if a test fails, the commit is made. How can I detect a test failure from my `pre-commit` file?

Comment: You need to get the result of `gulp test`. If it's success, then `exit 0` in `pre-commit` or do nothing. If it's failure, then exit with a non-zero number.

Comment: does the gulp exit with non-zero code if a test fail? How does it return the failure otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exit code of a Bash script is the exit code of the last command executed.
If `gulp test` fails,
it exits with non-zero,
which means failure,
and the commit should get aborted.

Are you sure the hook script gets executed?

- The script must be at `.git/hooks/pre-commit`
- The script must be executable

Assuming these conditions are met,
the script as posted should work as expected.
If it doesn't, then modify it to help debugging and post the output of an example commit that you expect to fail.

```
#!/bin/bash

gulp test

x=$?
echo exit code = $x
exit $x
```